# Python error - Lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a generalised program to see if a list B is contained inside a larger list A, however I'm having trouble getting the code below to return `True` in my program when this is the case.

```
n = len(A)
m = len(B)

any( B == A[j:j+m-1] for j in range(n-m+1) )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not getting any syntax errors with this code on Python 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The length of a slice `L[a:b]` is `b-a`, that's the beauty of Python slicing (exclusive the last element).

So the length of `A[j:j+m-1]` is `m-1`, so it can't be equal to `B` as that has length `m`.

Comment: Ah was simple, got it - thanks!Now works, but also wondering why we have to use n-m+1 for the range? Am I right in saying that the last 'j' that is called is n-m? This means we then check the list A[n-m:n] = B last - although the last possibly defined m-length sublist of A is A[n-m-1:n-1]. However on the back of this theory the program errors if I decrease the range by 1.

Comment: T132: if m is 1, then you need to try with all possible 1-character substrings, and that's exactly the strings A[j:j] with j from range(n). Only if the substrings are longer than 1 are there some indices that you know you don't have to look at.

Answer (score 2):

this `A[j:j+m-1]` returns a list shorter by 1 than B. change it to `A[j:j+m]`